# Certain rtf or docx files are not opening in Microsoft Word 2010 and no error is shown

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

On one of my computers Microsoft Word can't open certain rtf and docx files. The Word's intro window is shown  then nothing happens, the document is never opened and the intro animation goes forever.

[image]

Those files can be openned by Open Office with no problem or by MS Word on my other computer.

What may be the reason?

Comment: Instead of waiting for the splash to load, try opening Word by itself empty. Then try opening the file. Does it give you any errors?

Comment: Try reinstalling MS Office

Comment: @MC10 Checked already, does not help, but thank you for the effort.

Comment: Have you checked your Windows application event log for faults?